# How to determine whether there are any records in a given Partition Range

Tags: sql-server, database-partitioning

Given a SQL Server Partition Function, with multiple ranges, used by multiple tables/indexes, I want to identify which ranges (and whether the 2nd range, in particular) do or don't contain data anywhere in the database.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The following query will return (likely duplicated) counts of records in a given partition range, or a given partition scheme, across all tables/indexes:

```
    SELECT scheme.[name], tab.[name], ind.[name], part.partition_number, rows
      FROM sys.partition_schemes AS scheme 
      JOIN sys.indexes AS ind
        ON ind.data_space_id = scheme.data_space_id
      JOIN sys.tables AS tab
        ON tab.[object_id] = ind.[object_id]
      JOIN sys.partitions AS part
        ON part.index_id = ind.index_id
        AND part.[object_id] = tab.[object_id]   
      WHERE scheme.[name] = 'MyPartitionScheme'
        AND partition_number = 2 --Or whichever partition you're interested in.
```

Note that a table that has multiple indexes with the same rows in the same partition, will "double count".

So this query is ONLY useful for determining whether a partition has 0 records, or "more than zero" records. *(Fortunately that's exactly what I wanted to do :) )*

Comment: This seems uglier than I'd been hoping - I feel like a `sys.partition` should have a direct link to "which partitioning function/scheme am I in?" Am I missing anything?

Comment: (P.S. https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Cunningham%27s_Law :P )

Comment: The joins look correct. Not sure why you think it's only useful for that, it also tells you exactly how many rows it has. To prevent double counting, filter on `ind.index_id IN (0, 1)` either heap or clustered.

Comment: Mind you, it depends what you are trying to show: you might *want* to know how many rows per partitioned index (remember an index could be filtered), but if not then you might need a subquery `select top 1` for the index

Comment: @Charlieface suppose I have 2 indexes on a partitioned table, both of which cover the whole table, but on different columns (+ the partition key, of course). And suppose that there's only a single row in the table. Then that row will get counted under both indexes. Thus if I wanted to know "how many records do I have associated with Partition X, then I would get the answer '2'. Not '1', which is the actual truth.

Comment: It depends what you call a "row". Each index has a copy of the data, so it's not ridiculous to say there are two rows. But if you want to know how many rows are in a partitioned table, counting eaach row only once, and all partitioning is always done on the clustered index, then you can just filter to the clustered index as mentioned